# Variable declaration issue while using useState Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

While using the below code, i face the issue of title can't be reassigned.

```
const ExpenseItem = ({ date, title, amount }) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(title);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setTitle("updated");
  };
```

For a work-around, I'm doing as below.

```
const ExpenseItem = ({ date, title, amount }) => {
  let setTitle;
  [title, setTitle] = useState(title);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setTitle("updated");
  };
```

Is that the correct way ?

Comment: `title` is already declared in the `props` spreading. Rename one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Change one of the variables

```
const ExpenseItem = ({ date, title: titleProp, amount }) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(title);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setTitle("updated");
  };
}
```

or

```
const ExpenseItem = ({ date, title, amount }) => {
  const [titleState, setTitle] = useState(title);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setTitle("updated");
  };
}
```